# How does perl process a csv file

Tags: perl, csv

```
  while ( <IN_FILE> )
  {
    chomp;
    # do some processing

  }
```

1. how does Perl process a file, is it the usual line by line?
2. what constitutes a line? What if it's reading a csv file?
3. When I edit a csv file which opens in notepad on windows for example, with word wrap off it's just a huge block of text, there are about 30 lines of text and they break off at the same spot so I'm assuming thats because it reached the end of the row limit which is something like 1024 chars per line I believe?
4. So how would perl parse that?
5. Is it treated as one statement or what, are there are newline chars?

Comment: That's a lot of questions.

Comment: Perl does whatever *you* tell it to do. If you're dealing with CSV files you should look at the `Text::CSV` module from CPAN: http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.32/lib/Text/CSV.pm

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: A permanent link that is not tied to a specific version or even a specific author is http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-CSV/  That link will always point to the latest/greatest for whoever reads this question months or years down the road.

Comment: better yet, metacpan links provide both permalinks -- the version linked, and the latest. e.g. the left hand side of https://metacpan.org/module/Text::CSV#SYNOPSIS

Comment: @AndyLester My mistake, I grabbed the first URL from Google assuming it was the direct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl processes CSV files just like any other text file.

Your file looks funny in Notepad because your file was created on Unix and has Unix line ends (\n only). Notepad expects Windows line ends (\r\n (or is it the other way round?)). Use WordPad or a more advanced editor on Windows to see Unix line ends. Better yet, look at your file in a Unix editor.

Answer (score 1):

1. yes
2. lines are some characters ending in a "end of line" character.  The symbol in perl for an end of line character is `\n`.  Most file reading operations "know" about end of line characters and behave accordingly
3. the line length isn't important
4. perl would parse your skeleton code by setting the special variable `$_` to the current line being read from the file.  Then if it was csv you could read convert the fields with something like this `my @fields = split(/,/,$_)`  $field[0] would be the first csv item in that line and $field[1] the second and so on.  perl has ready made modules like Text::CSV to make this sort of thing easier and deal with odd cases
5. perl "understands" newline characters and deals with them appropriately

Comment: When reading in lines are a length of text ending with the value of $\ which deafults to \n

Comment: @user1937198 mate, ``$\`` is important when dealing with outputting data in lines.  And you are quite right, it defaults to ``\n``

Comment: @user1937198 again, you are right.  ``$/`` is the input record separator and could be used to alter the default from newline to something else! Of course ``$\`` is undef!  What was I thinking!! We should be a crime fighting team or something :)

Answer (score 0):

1. When using the `<IN_FILE>` syntax, yes, line-by-line.
2. Probably a sequence of 0 or more characters separated by a `\n`, possibly `\r\n` on some platforms.  See @HunterMcMillen's comment for a great CSV suggestion.
3. Don't trust notepad for windows - for many reasons... See @Arkadiy's answer
4. Better than notepad, line-by-line like #2
5. Don't know what you mean.  If there is a newline character, it will be a line separator.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer the broader question, "how can I deal with a CSV file in Perl" - to which there are many answers, but one of the more common ways is by "using the Text::CSV module"

Plenty of example code at https://metacpan.org/module/Text::CSV#SYNOPSIS, but for a briefer example, here's what I did at work this afternoon:

```
# now we expect a CSV file on STDIN
while (<>) {
  $csv->parse($_);

  # grab the field values
  my ( $agreement, $debt_id, $client_id, $campaign_id ) = $csv->fields();
  # less interesting code goes here
}
```

Plenty people have addressed your specific individual questions, but if your problem is "how do I handle this CSV", then regardless of newlines/commas etc inside fields, this should Just Work.

As for the lack of newlines in your file -- as others have said, that's probably just a Windows/Unix line endings issue. As long as they're consistent (which it seems they are -- none of them work on Windows!) you're fine.